# Different color in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a hyperlink by following this link

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links

on my code ,however am getting a different color with Internet Explorer ,but in Mozilla and chrome they are the same .

How to solve the issue.

Here is the code of html

```
  <div class="Trial" >

    <p>The <a href="https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=uTnVUtTTC8m4rgfx-4HQBg">MyTrial</a>, My Text.</p>
```

Comment: Post your `HTML` and `CSS`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it did not include valid code to reproduce it. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: You don't seem to have posted any `CSS`, are you using any? If not, then the link colour will be whatever the browser uses. So you should use CSS to style the `a` tag. `a { color:#000; }` for example.

Comment: not currently using anything in css

Comment: Browsers have their own default stylesheets, and they differ, the default blue colour is different in `Firefox` compared to `IE11` for example. If you want to have the same colour, then style the links in `CSS`

Comment: thanks Nick R for your suggestions ,I am working on that.

Thanks

Comment: But I still dint understood why I got a downvote ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u added a style for links ?

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to inherit the style?  IE doesn't like that.

.trial a {color:}

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in your browser settings.
You can set them for IE by going to Internet options -> General -> Appearance -> Colors
Both visited and unvisited hyperlink colors can be set.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to default colors being used, if you wish to fix them yourself you can do the following either in a css file or in styles

```
<style>
a{
 color:red;
}
a:visited{
 color:pink;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Replace `<!DOCTYPE html> with this`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

2)add in your css file

```
a {
color: #YourColor
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 1) The OP never mentioned which DOCTYPE he was using, 2) the question is about HTML, so an XHTML DOCTYPE is out of place, and 3) even if you're going to recommend another DOCTYPE, please no Transitional. It only encourages bad practices by letting the validator allow things like `<center>`.